# BulkLoader.main in cassandra-all(Ver.4.1.3) error occurred : java.io.IOException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:7000 for streaming data

Tags: java-11, bulkloader, cassandra-4.0

I'm using BulkLoader.main to import SSTable files into Cassandra and I'm getting an error.

■The following dependencies are used:

```
cassandra-all: 4.1.3
cassandra-driver-core: 3.6.0
```

Java 11

■Error:
※The error occurs on cassandra 3.11

```
Established connection to initial hosts
Opening sstables and calculating sections to stream
Streaming relevant part of /tmp/sstable/my_keyspace/example/nb-2-big-Data.db  to [/127.0.0.1:7000]
2023-10-11 05:19:40.857 [main] ERROR o.a.c.streaming.StreamSession - [Stream #c7851460-67f5-11ee-8145-0d5fb7e092f8] Streaming error occurred on session with peer 127.0.0.1:7000
java.io.IOException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:7000 for streaming data
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.async.NettyStreamingConnectionFactory.connect(NettyStreamingConnectionFactory.java:67)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoadConnectionFactory.create(BulkLoadConnectionFactory.java:72)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoadConnectionFactory.create(BulkLoadConnectionFactory.java:47)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoadConnectionFactory.create(BulkLoadConnectionFactory.java:32)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.async.StreamingMultiplexedChannel.createControlChannel(StreamingMultiplexedChannel.java:169)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.async.StreamingMultiplexedChannel.setupControlMessageChannel(StreamingMultiplexedChannel.java:161)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.async.StreamingMultiplexedChannel.sendControlMessage(StreamingMultiplexedChannel.java:197)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.start(StreamSession.java:379)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamCoordinator.startSession(StreamCoordinator.java:267)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamCoordinator.access$700(StreamCoordinator.java:41)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamCoordinator$HostStreamingData.connectAllStreamSessions(StreamCoordinator.java:313)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamCoordinator.connectAllStreamSessions(StreamCoordinator.java:112)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamCoordinator.connect(StreamCoordinator.java:106)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.createInitiator(StreamResultFuture.java:106)
        at org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamPlan.execute(StreamPlan.java:181)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:199)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.load(BulkLoader.java:91)
        at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:58)
        at xx.xx.App.doBulkLoader(JavaDriverCore4170App.java:122)
        at xx.xx.App.main(JavaDriverCore4170App.java:116)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:7000
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused
        at io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.throwConnectException(Errors.java:124)
        at io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.finishConnect(Socket.java:251)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.doFinishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:673)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractEpollChannel.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe.epollOutReady(AbstractEpollChannel.java:530)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:470)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
progress: total: 100% 0.000KiB/s (avg: 0.000KiB/s)
```

cassandra-all (Ver.4.1.3) doesn't seem to be able to connect to port 7000 of cassandra, i don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: the error occuirred in Cassandra 3.11: 
IncomingStreamingConnection.java:90 - Error while reading from socket from /172.18.0.1:45262.
java.io.IOExeption: Received stream using protocol version 12 (my version 4). Terminating connection
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingStreamingConnection.run(IncomingStreamingConnection.java:66)